# concurrent reads using mongo client take more than 10sec

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We are using Cosmos db with Mongo API and read aggregate query is taking more than 10sec when there are concurrent calls during a load test.

Below is a sample query, which takes around 1 sec when individually ran but taken up to 15sec in a load test where there are upto 50 concurrent users.

Any inputs are appreciated

```
const foundRecords = await db
        .collection('records')
        .aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              userId: 9221,
            },
          },
          {
            $unwind: '$records',
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: '$recordId',
              count: {$sum: 1},
            },
          },
        ])
        .toArray();
```

Comment: What is the total data size that is being aggregated? Are there any indexes in the database?

Comment: data size is not much, we are using 3.2 version and I believe indexes are auto created for all properties.